# Representing Language codes according to standards

Tags: web-services, rest, standards, iso, country-codes

Each language code is represented by 2 digit language code and 2 or 3 digit country code. For eg. English US is represented as `en-us`, and Japanese is represented as `ja-jp`.

I followed `ISO-3166` to fetch country codes. I need to publish the exact language codes to my users and I want to follow standards. My questions are :

1) Is it mandatory to use hyphen between two codes or underscore is also correct ? For eg. `en-us` or `en_us` , which one is correct ? I couldn't found anything regarding this in ISO codes.

2) Is it mandatory to strictly follow these country codes ?, for eg. Japanese `ja-jp`, can it also be represented as `ja-ja` ?

Comment: Not necessary a duplicate, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152321/what-is-a-good-definition-for-language-code-and-locale-codes

Comment: Thanks , a good refence